# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_root' on one system but not another

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to get my python program to run on another PC. On my other one it runs without problems, but here I get this error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\EEG\experiment\pyspantask_WMload-main (3)\pyspantask_WMload-main\pyspantask_LSL.py:909: DeprecationWarning: isDaemon() is deprecated, get the daemon attribute instead
  self.oddballTrainingThread.isDaemon()
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\EEG\experiment\pyspantask_WMload-main (3)\pyspantask_WMload-main\pyspantask_LSL.py:1142: DeprecationWarning: isDaemon() is deprecated, get the daemon attribute instead
  self.oddballTrainingThread.isDaemon()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\EEG\experiment\pyspantask_WMload-main (3)\pyspantask_WMload-main\pyspantask_LSL.py", line 2017, in <module>
    mainThead = threading.Thread(target=mainthread(), daemon=True);
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\EEG\experiment\pyspantask_WMload-main (3)\pyspantask_WMload-main\pyspantask_LSL.py", line 1820, in mainthread
    main_frame = MainFrame(root,
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\EEG\experiment\pyspantask_WMload-main (3)\pyspantask_WMload-main\pyspantask_LSL.py", line 765, in __init__
    self.display_var = tkinter.StringVar("")
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 540, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 372, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_root'
```

I have already reinstalled Python and have no idea what the problem is, because I'm only starting a thread at this line.
Can anyone tell me what to do here?

This is the whole main method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":



# Read configuration:
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage: %s config_file [results_file]" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print("Config file:", sys.argv[1])
    config_file = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    results_file = request_subject_id() + ".tsv"
    time_file = request_subject_id() + "time" + ".tsv"
else:
    print("results file:", sys.argv[2])
    results_file = sys.argv[2]
    time_file = "time_" + sys.argv[2]

# Check if the output file already exists:
while os.path.exists(results_file):
    print("A results file for this subject id already exists.")
    print("Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n)")
    if sys.stdin.readline().strip() == "y":
        open("time_" + sys.argv[2], 'w').close()
        break
    else:
        results_file = request_subject_id() + ".tsv"
        time_file = "time_" + request_subject_id() + ".tsv"

# print("Sven test")
# Load and sanity check the configuration:

exec(open(config_file).read())

with ask_if_warnings(lambda: sys.exit(1), "There were warnings.  Do you want to proceed?"):

    # Make sure that all parameters are present in the configuration file.
    t = set("""fontname fontname processing_items_file target_items_file responses
  welcome_text instructions1 allow_sloppy_spelling practice_processing_items
  measure_time_after_trial heed_order pseudo_random_targets practice_levels
  practice_items_per_level practice_correct_response
  practice_incorrect_response practice_summary instructions2 instructions3
  levels items_per_level next_message finished_message
  time_out_factor time_out_message target_display_time response_display_time
  good_bye_text""".split())
    if set(dir()).intersection(t) != t:
        raise ValueError("Some settings are missing: "
                         + ', '.join(t.difference(set(dir()))))

    # If there is just one level specified in the
    # configuration file, we have to wrap it in a tuple:
    if type(practice_levels) != tuple:
        practice_levels = (practice_levels,)
    if type(levels) != tuple:
        levels = (levels,)

    # All levels should be integer values:
    if False in [type(x) == int for x in practice_levels]:
        raise ValueError("All values in practice_levels shoud be integer values.")
    if False in [type(x) == int for x in levels]:
        raise ValueError("All values in levels shoud be integer values.")

    # Check target items:

    # Check if targets are unique:
    t = [l.strip() for l in open(target_items_file, encoding='utf-8')]
    if len(t) != len(set(t)):
        warn("There are duplicates in the list of targets: "
             + ', '.join(duplicates(t)))

    # The number of target items must be larger than the size of the
    # largest level:
    if len(t) <= max(practice_levels + levels):
        raise ValueError("There are too few target items for the largest set size.")

    # Check if the targets are single letters/numbers
    single_letters = all(len(x) == 1 for x in t)

    # Warn if the number of targets is not resonably bigger than the
    # max level:
    if len(t) < 2 * max(practice_levels + levels):
        warn("There are very few target items.  They might repeat too often.")

    # In case sloppy spelling is allowed, check if the target items have
    # a sufficient damerau levenshtein distance to be unambiguously
    # identifyable:
    if allow_sloppy_spelling:
        for i in range(0, len(t)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(t)):
                if damerau_levenshtein(t[i], t[j]) < 2:
                    raise ValueError((
                                                 "These target items are too similar to be used with sloppy spelling: %s, %s" % (
                                         t[i], t[j])).encode("utf-8"))

    # Check processing items:

    # Have enough practice trials for reliable time estimate:
    if practice_processing_items - measure_time_after_trial < 1:
        raise ValueError("Too few practice trials for getting a time estimate.")
    if practice_processing_items - measure_time_after_trial < 6:
        warn(
            "Too few practice trials give you an unreliable estimate of the time needed by the participant to do the task.")

    # Have unique processing items:
    t = [l.strip() for l in open(processing_items_file, encoding='utf-8')]
    if len(t) != len(set(t)):
        warn(("There are duplicates in the list of operations: "
              + ', '.join(duplicates(t))).encode("utf-8"))

    # Have enough processing items:
    no_targets = sum(practice_levels) * practice_items_per_level
    no_targets += sum(levels) * items_per_level
    if no_targets > len(set(t)):
        raise ValueError("Not enough verification items. Only %d instead of %d." % (
            len(set(t)), no_targets))

    # See that the resposes in the processing_items_file are the same
    # as those in the configuration:
    r = set([l.split("\t")[1] for l in t])
    if set(responses.keys()) != r:
        raise ValueError("There is a response other than y and n for at least one verification item.")

# End sanity checks.

# Store  ant settings:

store_line("# Settings:")
store_line("# subject id = %s" % results_file.split(".")[0])
store_line("# allow_sloppy_spelling = %s" % allow_sloppy_spelling)
store_line("# heed_order = %s" % heed_order)
store_line("# time_out_factor = %s" % time_out_factor)

# start time file:
store_line_time("time\tkey\texpected\t entered")

# Prepare material:

if pseudo_random_targets:
    target_items = ShuffledItems(target_items_file)

else:
    target_items = RandomItems(target_items_file)

processing_items = shuffled_lines(processing_items_file)



root = tkinter.Tk()
# start the pyspan task
mainThead = threading.Thread(target=mainthread(), daemon=True);
mainThead.start()
```

Comment: add your Code to help us fix your problem

Comment: *Or* provide a [mre] (i.e. not your whole program).

Comment: I added my main method

Comment: No, you should really create a [mcve]. In any case, you should ask yourself why you have a `str` there and not an object that has a `_root` attribute. That is the key to your problem. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter when initializing a tkinter variable is a widget that tkinter can use to determine what window owns the variable.

Consider the following code:

```
self.display_var = tkinter.StringVar("")
```

In the above code you're passing the empty string, which is not a widget. When tkinter tries to find the root window for that string it is examining the `_root` property, but a string doesn't have a `_root` property, hence the error message.

If you're trying to initialize the widget to the empty string, you must assign the value to the `value` attribute:

```
self.display_var = tkinter.StringVar(value="")
```

Comment: How does this explain why the code works on one system and not the other one?

Comment: @martineauI I would be surprised if the OP's code actually worked on another system. Maybe they were running an older version of tkinter? The first parameter is very clearly `master` if you look at the source code, and `""` is not a valid value for `master`.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with anything you said about how to properly initialize the value of a `StringVar` nor why doing it wrong would cause the reported exception, merely the lack of consistency claimed by the OP. AFAIK, it's *always* been that way, even in older versions of Python and `tkinter`.